# Beaglebone black autorun nodejs project

Tags: node.js, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I have a Beagle bone black and a nodejs project in a folder with multiple files. How do I autorun if the power goes out and it re-starts? Currently I have the project located in the autorun folder but it will not start on re-boot. It will work if I start manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works with nodejs, but there is a autostarting service you may try:
http://beaglebone.cameon.net/home/autostarting-services

Answer (score 0):

You can put a file in Cloud9's /autorun folder that requires the other files of your project that are in a different folder.

In the file you put in the /autorun folder, you need to change the relative paths to your included files from:
`var Server = require("./server");`

to:

`var Server = require("../myProject/server");`